Shutting down NameNode datanode resource manger etc immediately on running hadoop
C:\hadoop-3.3.6\sbin>.\start-dfs.cmd

after running above command command prompt opens for datanode and namenode but it immediately shutdown what should i do
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are not accessible or do not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:808)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:694)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:1033)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:1008)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1782)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1847)
2024-04-11 17:46:20,780 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7dcc91fd{hdfs,/,null,STOPPED}{file:/C:/hadoop-3.3.6/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps/hdfs}
2024-04-11 17:46:20,792 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@200606de{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9870}
2024-04-11 17:46:20,792 INFO server.session: node0 Stopped scavenging
2024-04-11 17:46:20,795 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@52350abb{static,/static,file:///C:/hadoop-3.3.6/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps/static/,STOPPED}
2024-04-11 17:46:20,796 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3aee3976{logs,/logs,file:///C:/hadoop-3.3.6/logs/,STOPPED}
2024-04-11 17:46:20,801 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2024-04-11 17:46:20,802 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2024-04-11 17:46:20,802 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2024-04-11 17:46:20,804 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are not accessible or do not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:808)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:694)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:1033)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:1008)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1782)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1847)
2024-04-11 17:46:20,805 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.io.IOException: All specified directories are not accessible or do not exist.
2024-04-11 17:46:20,818 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at LAPTOP-MP0V5LBJ/192.168.14.19
************************************************************/ 


I tried to install new version of microsoft visual c++
Folder like these needs to deleted app/data/temp something I saw on
stackoverflow someones ans but in my case no folder like that to
delete.


Did you try running Hadoop in administrator mode? as the message says, it's not accessible, probably due to mismatch permission.
